# Install pyspec module in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

After installing Anaconda with python3 under C (Path: C:\Anaconda)and setting the path to the environmental variables in windows 10 system, I try to install "pyspec" module to Anaconda in command lines. It turns out to the following messages:

```
C:\Users\Timothy>pip install pyspec
Collecting pyspec
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/36/fdcd349f2873a5ebd16b7ba2ed4c869a7474e1a77c2f1b6371ff2cfe0ee3/pyspec-0.2-r213.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Timothy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a766ikbc\pyspec\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "C:\Users\Timothy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a766ikbc\pyspec\ez_setup.py", line 106
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Timothy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a766ikbc\pyspec\
```

And I have no idea what happened. Could anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think setting the path of Anaconda to the environmental variables is fine. Becuase I can enter anaconda by typing conda in command lines. (?)  Maybe pyspec is not updated and supported any more. I'll try some other modules.

Answer (score 1):

One of the files in `pyspec`, namely the file `ez-setup.py`, has the line

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
```

Unfortunately, that syntax is acceptable in Python 2 but not in Python 3. The Python 3 syntax is

```
except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as e:
```

This shows that `pyspec` was written for Python version 2 and will not work with Python version 3. [Its PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pyspec/) shows that the package has not been updated since July 21, 2011. Most worrying, there are no versions of Python listed for the package. That means it was indeed written for Python 2 and has not been updated to Python 3.

Your best bet is to use another package. Using such an old, outdated package is not wise. If you really want to try, you could use `2to3` or something similar to attempt to convert `pyspec` to Python 3. But that would probably be a nightmare.

You could try to contact the authors, Stuart B. Wilkins and Certified Scientific Software, for updated code. (Contact info is in [that PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pyspec/)).